# Threadpooling on one instance of class, how to wait till all threads are complete?

Tags: c#, threadpool

Consider the code below. I do not want to create multiple instances of `class Waiter`. (So I cannot use ManualResetEvent class)

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

    public class Waiter
    {
        static int counter=0;
        static int max=20;

        public void Start()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++)
            {
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(DoWork, (object)i);

            }
            Console.Read();//without this line the application quits before all threads are complete :(

        }

        public void DoWork(object o)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

            }
            finally
            {
                counter++;
                Console.WriteLine(counter);
                if (counter==max )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("All threads complete");
                }
            }



        }

    }

    public class ThreadPoolExample
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            Waiter wtr=new Waiter();
            wtr.Start();



        }
    }
```

I have two problems with the above code

1>Without the  `Console.Read()` the application quits before all threads end.

2>The statement  `Console.WriteLine("All threads complete");` executes twice.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx) instead, and then you can do [Task.WaitAll(tasks);](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695.aspx)

Also, instantiate your tasks through the factory:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Console.Writeline(""); });
```

It will use the thread pool for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [Interlocked.Increment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c.aspx) to increment `counter`.  As it is there is a race condition when two threads try to increment it at the same time.

If you want to have multiple instances of `Writer` working at the same time then you can't have a static `counter` variable.  They'll fight with each other.  Just make it a private instance variable and you should be fine.  Max should either be `const` or `readonly` (and stay static) if it never changes, or it should also be an instance field if it can change.

And finally, if you have a non-static `ManualResetEvent` instance you can create it in `Start`, initialize it to set, wait for it at the end of the loop, and then signal it when the last thread finishes (where you currently just write to the console).